# PHP5 zval container vs PHP7 zval container. How references & variables are stored now?

Tags: php, php-internals

I am following a tutorial & reading through some articles on how variables are stored in PHP using zval (zend value) container. Most of those articles seem to be following & getting information from the documentation on [php.net doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php). I got curious about how `zval` struct is implemented in PHP's core, so I opened up the source code from PHP8 & it looks different than what those articles or the php.net are stating. For example, in php.net it states that `zval` container contains `refcount` and `is_ref` but those two are not part of the source code when I look at it in PHP8. So after some digging, I found out that `refcount` & `is_ref` were part of `zval` struct back in PHP5 but then changed in PHP7 which introduced performance optimizations including better memory management.

This is the struct code for `zval` from PHP5:

```
struct _zval_struct {
    zvalue_value value; 
    zend_uint refcount__gc;
    zend_uchar type;    
    zend_uchar is_ref__gc;
};
```

This is what it looks like since PHP7 in PHP8:

```
struct _zval_struct {
    zend_value        value;            /* value */
    union {
        uint32_t type_info;
        struct {
            ZEND_ENDIAN_LOHI_3(
                zend_uchar    type,         /* active type */
                zend_uchar    type_flags,
                union {
                    uint16_t  extra;        /* not further specified */
                } u)
        } v;
    } u1;
    union {
        uint32_t     next;                 /* hash collision chain */
        uint32_t     cache_slot;           /* cache slot (for RECV_INIT) */
        uint32_t     opline_num;           /* opline number (for FAST_CALL) */
        uint32_t     lineno;               /* line number (for ast nodes) */
        uint32_t     num_args;             /* arguments number for EX(This) */
        uint32_t     fe_pos;               /* foreach position */
        uint32_t     fe_iter_idx;          /* foreach iterator index */
        uint32_t     property_guard;       /* single property guard */
        uint32_t     constant_flags;       /* constant flags */
        uint32_t     extra;                /* not further specified */
    } u2;
};
```

So I am trying to find some updated/relevant information about this and can't seem to find a good explanation that would include some illustrations on how it compares to PHP5 or is documentation on php.net still relevant? Does ref counting no longer matter since PHP7 or how does it handle the references now. Before it was relying on `is_ref` to determine whether it should copy on write or simply point to the same `zval` container. How does the copy on write mechanism work now?

For example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = $a;
```

This would in PHP5 have a single `zval` container where both `$x` & `$y` symbols would be pointing to, it would only create a copy of the container if either `$a` or `$b` changed the value but since PHP7 from my understanding it will have two two `zval` containers from the beginning since the value is a simple scalar type `int`. When does it do `copy on write`?

I don't know C language, which is why I'm having a hard time understanding whats going on by simply looking at the source code and the information I find online does not line up with the current state of PHP.

Comment: If you don’t know C, why do you think you’re going to be able to understand what’s going on by reading the source code? Go with what the documentation tells you.

Comment: @prieber because it does not line up with the source code. I know little bit of C but not to the point where I can read & understand everything. But I know enough to tell that what documentation is stating is different from whats in the code. As I showed code above, the current code in PHP does not have refcount & is_ref fields so Im not sure how it does ref counting & how references work now

Comment: If you think it’s wrong, tell them - https://www.php.net/get-involved.

Comment: I would love to do that but before I make some suggestions I gotta understand the problem first properly which is why I posted it here. I might be wrong and documentation might be accurate so hope to get someone who is familiar with PHP internals answer

Comment: https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/zvals/memory_management.html (and the next page) may be of use. The core idea of refcounting stays the same, but gets shifted out of the zval into the held structure.

Comment: Thank you @NikiC. That is indeed helpful. So now each variable has its own zval container basically right? Even when you do something like $b = $a, in PHP5 this would simply point to same zval and copy and create new zval only on change, but now $b will have it's own zval from the beginning and zval will contain the actual value for simple types like integer/floats but for complex stuff like object/array it will just contain pointer to another structure, am I getting this correctly?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @NikiC sorry, one more question :). When working with objects $a = new A(); $b = $a; in this case do we have 2 zvals or 1 zval? From my understanding both $a is a symbol pointing to a zval container that contains the object identifier inside the value which then points to the complex data structure that contains the actual object. When we create $b & assign $a to it, we get a new symbol that points to the new zval container but the value is simply the same id as the one in $a. So we end up with a copy of the $as zval container so we have 2 zval containers. Is that true? Thanks alot

Comment: Each variable always has a separate zval, independent of the type. In this case, both $a and $b are separate zvals pointing to the same object.